# Symmetric RPC with AutobahnJS

Tags: javascript, websocket, autobahn

Using WAMP over Websocket, with AutobahnPy server and AutobahnJS client. I'd like to call a PRC method on the client from the server side, ie. I'd like my RPC to be symmetric. There is [an example with symmetric RPC](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/tree/master/examples/wamp/rpc/symmetric), but both sides are implemented in Python.

Is it possible to do it with a Javascript client? Looking through the docs and the source, I can't find a Javascript equivalent of [`registerForRpc` function](https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython/blob/master/examples/wamp/rpc/symmetric/client.py#L35).

Comment: AutobahnJS does not yet have symmetric RPC support (you can't expose an RPC endpoint).

Comment: @oberstet but what about that Python example on the Github? Is that not symmetric RPC? It even says so in the name of the example!

Comment: Yes, thats symmetric RPC. AutobahnPython has support for symmetric RPC, but not AutobahnJS.

Comment: @oberstet thanks for the reply! Just one more thing: that means the WAMP protocol is capable of symmetric RPC, just that the JS client does not support it? I'm looking into writing a Dart client, and would love to have symmetric RPC support, if possible.

Comment: Yes, WAMPv1 has basic support for symmetric RPC - and AutobahnPython supports that. And yes, AutobahnJS just does not yet support it.